# jQuery selector for a collection of checkboxes

Tags: jquery

This is a follow up to my last question. What I have is the following:

```
<div class="abc">
    <input  id="Response[0]" name="Response[0]" type="checkbox" />
    <input  id="Response[1]" name="Response[1]" type="checkbox" />
    <input  id="Response[2]" name="Response[2]" type="checkbox" />
    <input  id="Response[3]" name="Response[3]" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

I heard from lonesomeday that one way to check on the collection of check boxes was the following:

```
  $('.abc input').change(function() {
if ($('.abc input:checked').length) {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

But it seems that there might be a problem with the second line here. I think it's my fault as I changed the code to add a `div` and a `class`.

What happens is that when I debug the function is called but then I can't add a watch to check the value of `.abc input:checked`.  I guess I am doing something wrong as this does not look right for a variable name.

Can someone help here. Is the variable correct?

Thank you

Comment: [Seems to work...](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rRQu9/1/), on Chromium 11.x on Ubuntu 11.04. Bearing in mind you've not closed the `$(document).ready(function(){` in your posted jQuery.

Comment: Please explain in plain steps what do you want to do, and what should happen?

Comment: Actually I didn't have it within $(document).ready ...  What is supposed to happen is that once a user clicks on one of the <input> boxes then the property of a button is enabled.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, in which case you didn't close the `$('.abc input').change(function(){` ...sorry. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.abc input').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', true);
}
});
```

This will toggle the `#doCheckMark` disabled status as you toggle a checkbox value. Of course this will cause confusion since you have so many checkboxes in this scope. Are you wanting to toggle the disabled statement if all checkboxes are activated? If so try:

```
$('.abc input').change(function() {
if ($('.abc input:checked').length == 4) {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', true);
}
});
```

Comment: I would like to enable the toggle if one or more checkboxes are clicked.

Comment: Note it's a boolean property, so you can just do `$('.abc input').change(function() { $('#doCheckMark').prop('disabled', $('.abc input:checked').length > 0); });` and still be pretty clear on what the code's doing :)

Comment: @Nick, that's using your noodle, nice 1! @Dave try either my first snippet or what Nick has posted above. Either should work for you

Comment: I tried doing the following but it doesn't seem to work: 

if ($('.abc input:checked').length > 0) {

Comment: @Nick your code works. As soon as I click one or more checkboxes then the button is enabled. However when I unlick all check boxes then it stays enabled. I want to it to be enable when one or more checkboxes is clicked.

Comment: sounds like you have a syntax problem. Are you sure the `change` event is firing?

Comment: if ($('.abc input:checked').length > 0) {

After this point it always go the wrong {}. Seems like it's not getting the length correctly in the lnrbob example

Comment: I added the following to the code: var abc = 0;
abc = $('.abc input:checked').length;  When the debugger gets here it always reports that abc = 0 even when a few check boxes are clicked.

Comment: @lnrbob - Your code is now working for me. I am not sure why it was not working before. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UExaa/1/ please try using the code there in your page and le me know how it turns out! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
$('.abc input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($('.abc input:checkbox:checked:first').length){
        $('#doCheckMark').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else{
        $('#doCheckMark').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

You can [test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/HA8A2/4/)

It will attache a `change` event to the set of checkboxes, and trigger a `change` when the page is loaded, so the button will be disabled by default. Once the user checks/unchecks a checkboxs it will fire a `change` event, in which case it will check if there are any checkboxes checked at all. If there is any checkbox checked, it will leave the button enabled, otherwise it will disabled the button. You need to use the attribute `attr` here, not the property `prop`.